# MS Chart Grouping

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I am new for using MS Chart control. I need to customize Pie chart for displaying data as groups. Say I have 15 person's data for their salary. I need to display this data using group. Like 2 or 3 person have salary in range between 10K and 5 person have of 16K and similar can be thought of. I need to display only the range of salary. How can I achieve this using plain asp.net. I am not supposed to use any other support like MVC or google api kind of stuffs. Please help me in this.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You do it via SQL Query Dear.

by group by clause and where condition

Select employee from [table_name] where salary in between 10k and 20k group by salary.

use stored procedure or use case statement for making a string then you easily use it in you query.May be it help you .